# Few errors in assembly program. For amateurs

Tags: assembly

I have to make a program which will work as calculator. I wrote this:

```
push ds
push 0000H


data segment
    imsg1 db 13,10,'enter 1st number:$'
    imsg2 db 13,10,'enter 2nd number:$'
    imsg3 db 13,10,'sum:$'
    imsg4 db 13,10,'diff:$'
    imsg5 db 13,10,'div:$'
    imsg6 db 13,10,'product:$'
    num dw ?
    num2 dw ?
data ends
   MOV ax,data
   MOV ds,ax
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset imsg1
      int 21h
   mov cx,0
   mov bx,10
   mov num,0            ; Using num instead of dx, as we usually do, because we have to store another number too.

   r1:mov ah,01h        ; For storing first number
      int 21h          
      cmp al,13
      je yy
      sub al,48
      mov cl,al
      mov ax,num
      mul bx
      add ax,cx
      mov num,ax
      jmp r1  

   yy:
      ;to enter 2nd number  
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset imsg2
      int 21h

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov num2,0

       r2:mov ah,01h
       int 21h
       cmp al,13
       je yy1
       sub al,48
       mov cl,al
       mov ax,num2
       mul bx
       add ax,cx
       mov num2,ax
       jmp r2


    yy1:
    ;TO PRINT PROMPT MSG FOR SUM
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset imsg3
      int 21h

      mov ax,num                ; Move the numbers to registers before doing any operation
      mov bx,num2               ; Because we will also need the numbers for other operations
      add ax,bx                 ; Adding and storing in ax
      mov cx,0
      mov bx,10
      mov dx,0
    r3:                                 ; To print the sum
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r3
       mov ah,02h
       print:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print

       ;TO PRINT SUBTRACTION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
      mov dx,offset imsg4
      int 21h
       mov ax,num
       mov bx,num2
       sub ax,bx                ; Subtracting and storing in ax

       mov cx,0
      mov bx,10
      mov dx,0
    r4:                                 ; Printing the subtracted value
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r4
       mov ah,02h
       print1:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print1

       ;TO PRINT DIVISION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
       mov dx,offset imsg5
       int 21h
       mov dx,0
       mov ax,num
       mov bx,num2
       div bx                   ; Quotient stored in AX

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov dx,0
    r5:                                 ; Printing the Quotient
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r5
       mov ah,02h
       print2:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print2

       ;TO PRINT MULTIPLICATION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
       mov dx,offset imsg6
       int 21h
       mov dx,0
       mov ax,num
       mov bx,num2
       mul bx                   ; Solution in AX

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov dx,0
    r6:                                 ; Printing the solution
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r6
       mov ah,02h
       print3:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print3
ret
main endp
code ends
end main
```

And I have errors:

> line 5 (data segment) parser: instruction expected
>   line 18(mov dx,offset imsg1): comma or end of line expected
>   line 39(mov dx,offset imsg2): comma or end of line expected
>   line 62(mov dx,offset imsg3): comma or end of line expected
>   line 87(mov dx,offset imsg4): comma or end of line expected
>   line 112(mov dx,offset imsg5): comma or end of line expected
>   line 138(mov dx,offset imsg6): comma or end of line expected
>   line 162(main endp): error:parser:instruction expected
>   line 163(main ends): error:parser:instruction expected
>   line 164(end main): error:parser:instruction expected

I'm trying to solve them since week with no success. Sorry that I have putted whole code here, but it's not so long snippet so maybe someone can help me with this..
Thank you!

Comment: What assembler? Looks like Masm/Tasm code, the error messages look like they could be from Nasm...

Comment: Just a guess given unspecified syntax, but do you maybe need a colon after imsg1: and so on to get them recognized as labels?

Comment: I want to compile it in NASM. Adding colon didn't worked. I have resolved the first error by typing segment .data,  (there was also error in data ends, but I have deleted this line)

Comment: Why did you use TASM syntax if you planned to use NASM to assemble the code?

Comment: I didn't know that different compilator use different syntax. I found tutorial, I heard that NASM is better then other ones and I started to develop this app. Now, it's all clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest thing is probably to use the intended assembler... but I used to do a lot of M/Tasm translations. This is UNTESTED!... but assembles without complaint... My preference would be to assemble it to a .com file, but the original code is for an MZ file (requires a linker).

```
; nasm -f bin -o myprog.com myprog.asm
; or
; nasm -f obj myprog.asm
; link ???

; for -f obj, remove this line
org 100h

segment data
    imsg1 db 13,10,'enter 1st number:$'
    imsg2 db 13,10,'enter 2nd number:$'
    imsg3 db 13,10,'sum:$'
    imsg4 db 13,10,'diff:$'
    imsg5 db 13,10,'div:$'
    imsg6 db 13,10,'product:$'

segment .bss
    num resw 1
    num2 resw 1

segment .text
; if -f obj, put these lines back
;   MOV ax,data
;   MOV ds,ax

      mov ah,09h
      mov dx, imsg1
      int 21h
   mov cx,0
   mov bx,10
   mov word [num],0            ; Using num instead     of dx, as we usually do, because we have to store another number too.

   r1:mov ah,01h        ; For storing first number
      int 21h          
      cmp al,13
      je yy
      sub al,48
      mov cl,al
      mov ax,[num]
      mul bx
      add ax,cx
      mov [num],ax
      jmp r1  

   yy:
      ;to enter 2nd number  
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx, imsg2
      int 21h

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov word [num2],0

       r2:mov ah,01h
       int 21h
       cmp al,13
       je yy1
       sub al,48
       mov cl,al
       mov ax,[num2]
       mul bx
       add ax,cx
       mov [num2],ax
       jmp r2


    yy1:
    ;TO PRINT PROMPT MSG FOR SUM
      mov ah,09h
      mov dx, imsg3
      int 21h

      mov ax,[num]              ; Move the numbers to registers before doing any operation
      mov bx,[num2]             ; Because we will also need the numbers for other operations
      add ax,bx                 ; Adding and storing in ax
      mov cx,0
      mov bx,10
      mov dx,0
    r3:                                 ; To print the sum
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r3
       mov ah,02h
       print:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print

       ;TO PRINT SUBTRACTION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
      mov dx, imsg4
      int 21h
       mov ax,[num]
       mov bx,[num2]
       sub ax,bx                ; Subtracting and storing in ax

       mov cx,0
      mov bx,10
      mov dx,0
    r4:                                 ; Printing the subtracted value
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r4
       mov ah,02h
       print1:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print1

       ;TO PRINT DIVISION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
       mov dx, imsg5
       int 21h
       mov dx,0
       mov ax,[num]
       mov bx,[num2]
       div bx                   ; Quotient stored in AX

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov dx,0
    r5:                                 ; Printing the Quotient
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r5
       mov ah,02h
       print2:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print2

       ;TO PRINT MULTIPLICATION PROMPT
       mov ah,09h
       mov dx, imsg6
       int 21h
       mov dx,0
       mov ax,[num]
       mov bx,[num2]
       mul bx                   ; Solution in AX

       mov cx,0
       mov bx,10
       mov dx,0
    r6:                                 ; Printing the solution
       mov dx,0
       div bx
       add dx,48
       push dx
       inc cx
       cmp ax,0
       jg r6
       mov ah,02h
       print3:
        pop dx
        int 21h
       loop print3
ret
```

Comment: Thank you. I will have to improve code, but it will be easier now :)

Answer (score 2):

In the comments section you mention that you want to assemble the code using NASM, but the code is written using TASM/MASM syntax. There are some important differences between the two styles:

In TASM/MASM syntax this:

```
mov ax,num
```

Will load `ax` with the *value stored at* `num`. In NASM syntax it will load `ax` with the *address of* `num`. To get the TASM behavior in NASM you need to put brackets around the address:

```
mov ax,[num]
```

---

In TASM/MASM syntax this:

```
mov dx,offset imsg1
```

Loads `dx` with the address of `imsg1` (actually its offset within a segment). In NASM syntax that would simply become:

```
mov dx,imsg1
```

---

Some directives (like `ENDP`) are specific to TASM/MASM and have no real counterpart in NASM.